# Multiple Regression Analysis Beginner

Tags: r, multiple-regression, data-transformation, polynomial, fractional-polynomial

Background: I am using an instrument that measures two physical properties, X1~Temperture and X2~ Velocity. When gathering the data to make the curve a set of predetermined concentrations are chosen from the desired range, usually 1% to 25%. The temperature is varied in a control manner consistent across all concentrations. Each chemical has a different shape, some include inflection points in the data. This is a scatter plot of the raw data:

[image: Chemical being Tested at 1-8% Concentration]

I would like to perform regression analysis in R.

Questions: 1.) Is it valid to split the data into a training and validation set?

```
train.size <- 0.8
train.index <- sample.int(length(Conc), round(length(Conc)*train.size))
train.sample <- MYdata[train.index,]
valid.sample <- MYdata[-train.index,]
```

2.) Is there a standard way to approach this data that could be applied to multiple different chemicals? Example: nonlinear least squares, using the "NLS" function, or a way to estimate a polynomial or logarithmic transformation. I am not getting good data using NLS. The code I'm using is:

```
 NLS <- nls(Conc ~ b*Temp + c*SV, start=list(b= -1.3, c= -1.3))
```

3.) Would fractional polynomial be a good choice to try for this? I am unsure how to perform this, but it did seem promising.

Comment: I would just start with adding polynomial trend lines in Excel. It looks like a second-order polynomial should do fairly well, for a start.

Comment: I've tried a second order polynomial but am still getting unacceptably large residuals, +/-4% is the error it creates. Would there be another approach to try?

Comment: Well, you could always increase the order of the polynomial; try order 3 or 4.

Comment: Okay, I can't make this work in excel my errors continue to stay the same or go up, which doesn't make sense to me. Maybe I am doing this incorrectly? How do you had a trendline to a multiple regression in excel?